# What is limitting the minimum size of a QGraphicsView widget when in a layout?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

If I have a QGraphicsView widget on its own, I can resize it down to nothing, however once I put it in a layout it does not want to resize smaller than 70x70.

This does not appear to be a problem with a generic QWidget.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication([])
w = QWidget()

gv1 = QGraphicsView()
gv1.setMinimumSize(0,0)
gv2 = QGraphicsView()
gv2.setMinimumSize(0,0)

l = QGridLayout()
l.addWidget(gv1)
l.addWidget(gv2)

l.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
l.setSpacing(0)
w.setLayout(l)
w.show()
w.resize(100, 1)

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [`minimumSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop) documentation says:

> The minimum size set by this function will override the minimum size defined by QLayout. *In order to unset the minimum size, use a value of QSize(0, 0).*

This means that if you use `setMinimumSize(0, 0)`, you're *resetting* the minimum size, which will then default to the widget's (or layout) `minimumSizeHint()`.

A valid minimum size *direction* should always be at least 1.
Change to:

```
gv1.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
gv2.setMinimumSize(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions that helped me (in cpp) to make the `QGraphicsView` smaller were:
`setMaximumSize()` and `setSceneRect()`